# Fourier transform of Lorentzian distribution

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I have a Lorentzian function:

$$f(t)=\frac{a}{\pi}\frac{1}{t^2+a^2}$$

To take the Fourier transform, one would compute

$$\mathscr{F}[f(t)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{\pi}\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{t^2+a^2}dt$$

According to Mathematica, this evaluates to

$$
\mathscr{F}[f(t)]=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a^2}}e^{-a\omega}
$$

Several online integral calculators confirm this as well. However, it is not immediately clear to me how this integral would be evaluated analytically. This does not seem like a "standard" integral. So, my question is how would this integral be evaluated explicitly?